# Aplicação CONNECT BY - SQL Oracle - Busca DFS sem repetir linhas

Tags: sql

---

Prezados,
Suponhamos que um grafo esteja cadastrado de duas formas:

```
TABELA_A:

T | V1 | V2

1 | 1  | 2

2 | 2  | 3

3 | 2  | 4

4 | 4  | 5

TABELA_B:

T | V1 | V2

1 | 1  | 2

2 | 2  | 3

3 | 4  | 2 <====OBSERVEM QUE AQUI INVERTI OS VÉRTICES

4 | 4  | 5
```

Posto isso, preciso realizar a leitura de forma que eu faça varredura em todos as arestas "T", porém sem que entre em loop ou mesmo que ocorra a leitura de um trecho mais de uma vez.

Para tabela A, a solução se mostra simples:

```
SELECT v1, 
       v2 
FROM   tabela_a 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR b2 = b1
```

Por outro lado, a solução para a TABELA_B se torna um pouco mais complexa. Principalmente para situações análogas porém com uma quantia excessivamente maior de arestas. Por isso destaco a necessidade de ler uma única vez cada trecho ("aresta").
Uma solução "grotesca" porém eficaz para casos com poucas arestas que propuz, se resume a:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <== observe que tentei o   DISTINCT, 
                mas sem efeitos eficientes v1, 
                v2 
FROM tabela_a connect BY nocycle (prior b2 = b1) 
OR prior b2 = b2 ) 
OR prior b1 = b2 ) 
OR (prior b1 = b1 )
```

O exemplo apresentado é meramente ilustrativo. O caso que tenho em mãos é constituído por mais de 10.000 linhas e com esses casos de "inversão". Nada mais nada menos, preciso varrer o grafo seguindo a lógica do algoritmo de busca DFS (depth first search), semelhante ao que ocorre na leitura da TABELA_A, porém com possíveis inversões como apresentado. A solução para ler a TABELA_B é ruim, porque lê inúmeras vezes o mesmo trecho e depois filtra os singulares (através do DISTINCT). Isso é ruim, pois torna o processo muito lento.

Comment: Tente um union select t,va,vb from(select t,v1 va,v2 vb from tabela union select t,v2 va,v1vb from tabela , o connect by nesra tabela.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.v1, 
                a1.v2 
  FROM tabela_a a1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM tabela_a a2
                   WHERE a1.v1 = a2.v2
                     AND a1.v2 = a2.v1
                     AND a2.T < a1.T);
```

Comment: Olá @MarcosMessias, bem vindo ao **SOpt**. Na sua resposta poderia explicar um bocado o que fez para quem colocou a questão perceber melhor a sua solução.

Answer (score 0):

@MarcosMessias:

Interessante a solução. Porém cada tabela exige uma solução particular. Ambas descrevem um mesmo grafo, em que a coluna "T" nomeia as arestas e as colunas "V1" e "V2" nomeiam os vértices de cada aresta. Na tabela "TABELA_A",usando da solução apresentada ( a minha primeira solução ), a navegação ocorrerá da seguinte forma : (1 - 2) => (2 - 4) => (4 - 5) => (2 - 3) - Busca em Profundidade. A mesma solução para a tabela "TABELA_B" será : (1 - 2) => (2 - 3) - irá parar por aqui, pois é usado "PRIOR V2 = V1 ", ou seja, para que exista conexão nessa lógica o próximo trecho deve ter seu vértice "V1" igual ao vértice "V2" do seu montante. Mas, se observar, o trecho (4-2) está conexo, porém a lógica inicialmente proposta não é capaz de identificar. Preciso de uma solução que realize a seguinte leitura sem que ocorra repetição de trechos (arestas) :(1-2) => ( 4-2) => (4-5) => (2-3) - Busca em Profundidade. Caso possível, aconselho a desenhar a árvore descrita nas tabelas ( que é a mesma) e como ocorre a navegação, acho que isso ajudará a compreender o problema proposto. Agradeço a disponibilidade.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, Davi.

Criei a seguinte tabela para testar o select que você precisa:

```
CREATE TABLE TABELA_TESTE_DAVID (
   T  NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
   V1 NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
   V2 NUMBER(4) NOT NULL
);
```

e montei a seguinte query para tentar solucionar sua questão:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.t, t.v1, t.v2
  FROM TABELA_TESTE_DAVID t
 WHERE t.t in (SELECT t3.t
                 FROM TABELA_TESTE_DAVID t3
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM TABELA_TESTE_DAVID t2
                        WHERE t3.v1 = t2.v2
                          AND t3.v2 = t2.v1
                          AND t2.T < t3.T))
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR t.v2 = t.v1
        OR t.v2 = t.v2
        OR t.v1 = t.v2
        OR t.v1 = t.v1
```

Não sei se entendi exatamente o seu problema, mas veja se a solução que criei atende sua necessidade.
O sub-select dentro do WHERE filtra apenas as combinações únicas de v1 e v2 e o select principal faz conexão delas.

Espero ter ajudado.